# How to pass object context to an anonymous function?

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function

Is there a way of passing object context to an anonymous function *without* passing `$this` as an argument?

```
class Foo {
    function bar() {
        $this->baz = 2;
        # Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
        $echo_baz = function() { echo $this->baz; };
        $echo_baz();
    }
}
$f = new Foo();
$f->bar();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can assign `$this` to some variable and then use `use` keyword to pass this variable to function, when defining function, though I'm not sure if it is easier to use. Anyway, here's an example:

```
class Foo {
    function bar() {
        $this->baz = 2;
        $obj = $this;
        $echo_baz = function() use($obj) { echo $obj->baz; };
        $echo_baz();
    }
}
$f = new Foo();
$f->bar();
```

It is worth noting that `$obj` will be seen as standard object (rather than as `$this`), so you won't be able to access private and protected members.

Comment: Note: PHP v5.4 now allows the use of `$this` within anonymous functions.