# How to pass along object context

Tags: javascript

I have created the function below for getting the click count on a click. It works, but the problem is that when it calls `func`, `func` does not have the object context (ie `this`) that clickCount has.

In creating this question StackOverflow showed a link to the answer below, which is almost what I want, except that the function is defined with the context (or?). I want to apply the context in my clickCount handler

[How to pass object context to an anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330602/how-to-pass-object-context-to-an-anonymous-function)

How can I pass this on in my call to func in clickCount?

```
var clickCountObj = { //this is in the global context
  'clickTime' : 400
};


$.fn.clickCount = function (func) {
  $(this).click(function(e) {
    if (!clickCountObj.prevClickTime || clickCountObj.prevClickTime < Date.now() - clickCountObj.clickTime) {
      clickCountObj.clickCnt = 1;
    } else {
      clickCountObj.clickCnt = clickCountObj.clickCnt + 1;
    }
    clickCountObj.prevClickTime = Date.now();
    func(clickCountObj.clickCnt, e);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). It allows you to call a function and set `this` equal to the first argument.

```js
function displayName(greeting) {
  console.log(`${greeting}, I am ${this.first} ${this.last}`);
}

let me = {
  first: 'Mike',
  last: 'C'
};

displayName.call(me, 'Hello');
```

You could also use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) if you'd prefer to pass additional arguments as an array.

```js
function displayName(greeting) {
  console.log(`${greeting}, I am ${this.first} ${this.last}`);
}

let me = {
  first: 'Mike',
  last: 'C'
};

displayName.apply(me, ['Hello']);
```

Specifically for your case, try

```
func.call(this, clickCountObj.clickCnt, e);
```